# Python global variable changes by itself weirdly in a flask server

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, global-variables

I have been working on this bug for two days and still haven't gone anywhere.

Below is an abstraction of what I wanted to do: I have a flask server that changes global boolean variable `is_reading` to `True` upon a POST request 'read_start' made by the client. Similarly, `is_reading` is set to `False` upon 'read_end' request. I print out the value of `is_reading` in another thread every 1 second.
`is_reading` should always be `True` after 'read_start' request, but the result shows `is_reading` jumps between `True` and `False` indefinitely until 'read_end' is received (image attached at the bottom). I don't know what causes the weird change of `is_reading`. ChatGPT cannot give me a satisfiable solution. I tried adding `threaded=False` to `app.run` but nothing changed. Please help me!

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import time
import json
from flask_cors import CORS
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

is_reading = False

def print_reading_state():
    global is_reading
    while True:
        print('is_reading?', is_reading)
        time.sleep(1)

@app.route("/read_start",  methods=['POST'])
def read_start():
    global is_reading
    if request.method == 'POST': # POST request
        is_reading = True
        print('here! change is_reading to', is_reading)
        res = {'result': 'OK', 'status': 200}
        return jsonify(res)
    
@app.route("/read_end",  methods=['POST'])
def read_end():
    global is_reading
    if request.method == 'POST': # POST request
        is_reading = False
        print('here! change is_reading to', is_reading)
        res = {'result': 'OK', 'status': 200}
        return jsonify(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=print_reading_state)
        t1.daemon = True
        t1.start()
        app.run(debug=True)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('KeyboardInterrupt')
        is_reading = False
        t1.join()
        print('exit')
```

[`is_reading` after 'read_start' and 'read_end' is received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HycE1.png)

Comment: Aside: I don't think you need `if request.method == 'POST':` when you use `methods=['POST']` in the route.

Comment: Don't waste your time with ChatGPT for programming questions like this.

Comment: Please post the output as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: According to the documentation, using ```app.run``` in the main file is not recommended as it can lead to unwanted behavior. Instead, run the flask by using the command line and use the factory pattern.

Comment: I think it's because you're running two threads - try just removing all references to `t1`. Does the `print_reading_state` still get called?

Comment: @DaviA.Sampaio Thanks for your advice. I used `flask run` and no weird results since then. Like I mentioned, this example is an abstraction of the project I'm working on, which is a flask-socketio server and the second thread is for simulating the callback function for an eye tracker. It worked very well when I use `flask run` for my project as well, in case anyone encountered similar issues.

Comment: @WilliamWang That's good! I'll make it a response so it becomes more useful.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Flask.run), using `flask.Flask.run` method is not recommended as **it can lead to unwanted behavior**. Instead, [run the flask by using the command line](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) (`flask --app run` or similar). It's also good to use the [factory pattern](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/appfactories/#application-factories).